# How to get the email address for the current logged in user in EWS?

Tags: exchangewebservices

What is the correct way of getting a user's email address using EWS SOAP API's if I have the credentials (username & password) and the server address.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is as follow:

1. Create a AuthenticationContext
2. Setup a ClientCredential
3. Use AuthenticationContext to acquire a token
4. You will have to pass a callback which if the authentication is fine, you will receive AuthenticationResult in onSuccess of AuthenticationCallback
5. You can get the information from AuthenticationResult.UserInfo.DisplayableId